# How to authenticate multiple IMAP users to the same mailbox in Cyrus

Tags: email, postfix, imap, alias, mailbox

I have a standard Postfix/Cyrus setup with email account like account1@myhost.com. Users authenticate via IMAP. I want to create an email alias account like otheraccount1@secondhost.com and authenticate it to the same IMAP mailbox as account1@myhost.com.

Can I do this via Postfix aliases? What are the possibilities here.

Regards,
Angel

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like sharing the Mailboxes is the way to go.

Does this help?  [**http://oreilly.com/catalog/mimap/chapter/ch09.html#91630**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mimap/chapter/ch09.html#91630)